# How to cancel operation in xamarin.forms exrin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, exrin

I'm try to implement operation as ISingleOperation and Execute it with Execution.ViewModelExecute. I set timeout for 10 seconds and timeout dialog was shown, but execution was not stoped. How can i cancel operation?

Answer (score 1):

I need to pass CancellationToken to my methods

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396